# Props value is returning undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to get the value on input change but the value is undefined every time when I'm typing numbers

```
const Numbers = ({ onChange, value }) => {
    <Input 
    onChange={onChange}
    />
};

Numbers.propTypes= {
    value: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.number, PropTypes.string]),
    onChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};
Numbers.defaultProps {
    value: undefined
}
export default Numbers;
```

```
class UseNumbers extends React.Component {
    state={
        value: this.props.value
    };

    onChange = (name, value) => {
        console.log('value on change', value);
        this.setState({ value });
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <Number
                {...this.props}
                onChange={
                    this.onChange
                }
            />
        );
    }
    
}

UseNumbers.propTypes = {
    value: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.number, PropTypes.string])
};

UseNumbers.defaultProps = {
    value: undefined
};

export default UseNumbers;
```

I tried to log the value and here is undefined. In the Number function, I have put props value and onChange as well and seems to be ok, but I do not figure it out why the value is undefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`onChange` event handler is passed an `Event` object instead of `name` and `value` that you are expecting.

You could extract the name and value from the `Event` object using `Event.target` property. `Event.target.name` will contain the name of the input which triggered the `onChange` event and `Event.target.value` will the the latest value of that input.

Although react passes [Synthetic Event](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html) object to event handlers, instead of just [Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) object, synthetic event object is a cross-browser wrapper around the browser’s native event and has the same interface as the browser’s native event.

Change your event handler as shown below:

```
onChange = (event) => {
    // destructure name and value properties from event.target object
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    console.log('value on change', value);
    this.setState({ value });
};
```

**P.S.** You also need to add `name` attribute on the `input` element if you want to access the name of the input element which triggered the `onChange` event.

Comment: -> I tried to log only the event. but the target is null `target: null`

Comment: Event is returning: 
`
bubbles: null
cancelable: null
currentTarget: ƒ ()
defaultPrevented: null
dispatchConfig: null
eventPhase: null
isDefaultPrevented: ƒ functionThatReturnsFalse()
isPropagationStopped: ƒ functionThatReturnsFalse()
isTrusted: null
nativeEvent: null
target: null
timeStamp: ƒ (event)
type: null
_dispatchInstances: null
_dispatchListeners: null
_targetInst: null
`

Comment: your previous comment suggests that you are logging the event object. See the code in my answer. Its logging `event.target.value`.

Comment: yeah. I used your code and I got that in my previous comment

Comment: Thanks Yousaf, it worked. My project build was not good.

Answer (score 0):

your Numbers Component returns undefined,you sure your code works correctly?
no error thrown?

```
const Numbers = ({ onChange, value }) => {
    return <Input 
    onChange={onChange}
    />
};
```

the point is you onChange function:

```
onChange = (e) => {
    console.log('value on change', e.target.value);
    this.setState({value});
}
```

input element passed Event as first parameter to onChange function,
however, you mean this Input component is your custom component?